# How to disable card-view in a file after clicking submit button in another file

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview, android-cards

How I can access the `CardView` when the submit button is in another layout?

So basically after I click the submit button in File1.java, I want to make the cardview in Menu.java disabled and changed the color.

**File1.java**

```
buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextPage();
        }
    });

private void nextPage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
package com.example.test;
//all import statements

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = Menu.class.getSimpleName();

private final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    showStartDialog();

    CardView cardView1 = findViewById(R.id.card1);
    cardView1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//try to make cardview unclickable
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, File.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode ==REQUEST_CODE){
            if(data != null){
                boolean cardView1= data.getBooleanExtra("disable", false);
                Log.d(TAG,"code success 1");

                    if (cardView1) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "code success 2");
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}

//popup alert message , create dialog builder
private void showStartDialog(){
    String alert1 = "\nAnswer at least 5 surveys now!\n";
    String alert2 = "Redeem at information counter";
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>Collect mystery gift!</font>"));
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.gift);
    alert.setMessage(alert1 + "\n" + alert2);
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();
    Log.d(TAG, "popup appear");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In Menu.java have few cardview. After i click the cardview, then it will be directed to File1.java. So basically after I click the submit button in File1.java, I want to make the cardview in Menu.java disabled and changed the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `onActivityResult` method in your `Menu.java` file and instead of starting the `Menu.java` activity again, finish the current activity and use `setResult()`.

**Menu.java**

```
    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 101
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, File1.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
                  if(data != null){
                     boolean disableCard = data.getBooleanExtra("disableCard", false);

                     if(disableCard){
                        cardView1.setEnabled(false); 
                        cardView1.setOnClickListener(null);
                     } else {
                        cardView1.setEnabled(true); 
                        cardView1.setOnClickListener(this);
                     }

                  }
            }
        }
    }
```

**File1.java**

```
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            //set extras here that you want to pass back to Menu.java activity
            intent.putExtra("disableCard", true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried the code but my logic doesn't work.  if (disableCard){
                        cardView1.setEnabled(false);
                        cardView1.setClickable(false);
                        Log.d(TAG,"code success here too!");
                    }

Comment: So even after disabling the CardView, you are still able to click it?

Comment: yeah. Still able to click the CardView

Comment: okey, try the updated answer and if it still doesn't work then pls post your full code for Menu.java file.